# Convert db.Key to ndb.Key - Python on AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

It seems that db.Key and ndb.Key instances are not the same.

I have a db.Key instance. How do I convert it to an ndb.Key?

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
NDBEntity(ndb.Model):
  some_property = ndb.StringProperty()

DBEntity(db.Model):
  some_property = ndb.StringProperty()

# I have an instance of a DBEntity already saved in the datastore
db_entity_instance = DBEntity.all().get()

ndb_entity_instance = NDBEntity(id="some_id", parent=db_entity_instance.key(), some_property="foo").put()
# The above line doesn't work because it expects a Key Instance for the parent, and it doesn't seem to recognize a db.Key instance.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Using the two in the same app is probably a bad idea - you should port all your code over at once.

Comment: I agree with Nick except that there may be cases when converting an old style Model to a new one is prohibitively expensive.  In this case, it may be necessary to either temporarily work between old and new keys or create property references on new ndb models to old db.py models.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert from the "old" db.Key to the new ndb.Key. Take a look at [NDB Key Class](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/keyclass#Key_from_old_key) for more information.

Comment: I used "from_old_key(k): Returns an NDB key from the passed in "old" Datastore API (db) Key." Thanks!

Comment: What Albert said.  Use from_old_key.

Answer (score 4):

To convert DB key to NBD key you will have to :

```
ndb.Key.from_old_key(your_old_DB_key)
```

Take a look at [NDB Cheet Sheet](https://docs.google.com/a/searce.com/document/d/1AefylbadN456_Z7BZOpZEXDq8cR8LYu7QgI7bt5V0Iw/mobilebasic) for your further conversions.

Comment: But any ideas on how to actually CHANGE the old key to the new one in the production datastore?